# Slide animating layout

Tags: android, animation

I want to apply animation on layout[image]

when i click on arrow the slide meny look like
[image]

then clink on arrow reanimation the menu`enter code here`

Comment: do you want something like a sliding panel ?

Answer (score 3):

You can define an animation like this one that animates left to right and apply that to your layout:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
             android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
             android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

To apply animation to a layout resource:

```
Animation slideInLeft;
...
slideInLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_left);
mYourLayout.startAnimation(slideInLeft);
```

**Edit:**
When the animation is finished the layout will go back to the starting position. to avoid that you can use one of these 3 approaches:

1- Define an animation listener like this and hide your layout

```
anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
    }           
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
    }           
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
    }
});
```

2- Use a postDelayed Handler with the same duration has your animation duration and hide the layout at the end.

3- add this line to your animation:

```
anim.setFillAfter(true);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: u r right i do but when the layout go up its directly come down why is this so

Comment: You need to handle when the animation end. You can use 3 approaches and I will write them on the answer above as edited message

Comment: ok thanks for relpy but i use objectanimaotr and it work for me.

Comment: ObjectAnimator objectAnimator= ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mContent_container, "translationX", startX, endX);
objectAnimator.setDuration(1000);
objectAnimator.start();

Comment: but anther problem is that the below layout not change its position when this layout go up/down help me in htis